# Erro ao rodar o comando db:seed

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou estudando laravel na versão 5.2 e ao executar o comando php artisan db:seed retorna o seguinte erro:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Unable to locate factory with name [default] [CodePub\Models\User].

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersRolesPermissionsSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $user = factory(\CodePub\Models\User::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Admin da Silva',
        'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'password' => bcrypt(123456)
    ]);

    $roleAdmin = factory(\CodePub\Models\Role::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'description' => 'System Administrator'
    ]);

    $user->addRole($roleAdmin);

    $userManager = factory(\CodePub\Models\User::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Manager da Silva',
        'email' => 'manager@admin.com',
        'password' => bcrypt(123456)
    ]);

    $roleManager = factory(\CodePub\Models\Role::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Manager',
        'description' => 'System Manager'
    ]);

    $userManager->addRole($roleManager);

    $userSupervisor = factory(\CodePub\Models\User::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Supervisor da Silva',
        'email' => 'supervisor@admin.com',
        'password' => bcrypt(123456)
    ]);

    $roleSupervisor = factory(\CodePub\Models\Role::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Supervisor',
        'description' => 'System Supervisor'
    ]);

    $userSupervisor->addRole($roleSupervisor);

}
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(UsersRolesPermissionsSeeder::class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como está definindo os dados diretamente poderá usar somente o arquivo *DatabaseSeeder.php* como na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding) da seguinte forma:

```
 DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name'              => 'Admin da Silva',
            'email'             => 'admin@email.com',
            'password'          => bcrypt(123456),
        ]);
```

Agora, se for usar o *factory* juntamente com *fake*, faltou definir os modelos no arquivo *ModelFactory.php*, que seria algo assim:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
    ];
});
```

Para chamar o modelo definido acima na *factory* crie um *seeder*:

```
php artisan make:seeder TableNameSeeder
```

E chame da seguinte forma:

```
factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
```

Sendo o número **10** a quantidade de registros que deverão ser inseridos no banco dados.

E no arquivo que controla o *seed* -> *DatabaseSeeder.php*, chame a função normalmente como descrito na pergunta:

```
$this->call(TableNameSeeder::class);
```

Acho que é isso!

Espero ter ajudado!